# When SQLBulkCopy used with Using does close() get called automatically?

Tags: c#, using, sqlbulkcopy

I know when using SQLBulkCopy we have to use `close()` after using it. So I set the code like below and then I didn't need to add `bulkcopy.close()`?

As I know, the `using` statement calls `dispose()` method but sqlbulk copy doesn't have a `dispose` method.

Although I didn't set the `close()` in the using statement, does it automatically call `close`?

```
using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(NotifyService.ConnectionStringForSqlBulkCopy, SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers | SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: `Close` calls `Dispose` - https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.data/system/data/sqlclient/SqlBulkCopy.cs,789 The duplicate shows how the `Dispose` method is there using explicit interface implementation.

Comment: then when I using the Using statement it call close() method automatically and close() call dispose() method?

Comment: No. `using` calls `Dispose`.